# e.currentTarget for material ui buttons

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux, material-ui

- I have three tabs with three buttons.
- when I select button one it should show first button selected
- when I select button two it should show second button selected
- similarly for the rest of the buttons.
- I tried to achieve with e.currentTarget but not successful.
- can you let me know how to fix it.
- providing my code snippet and sandbox below.

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-c4f5u

```or-tag-here
class SimpleTabs extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      selectedButton: false,
      value: 0
    };
  }

  handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
    this.setState({
      value: newValue
    });
  };

  selectButton = e => {
    console.log("selectButton--->", e.currentTarget);
    console.dir("selectButton--->", e.currentTarget);
    const selectedButtonTarget = e.currentTarget;

    this.setState({ selectedButton: true });
  };
  renderButtonSelection = () => {
    if (this.state.selectedButton === true) {
      return (
        <div>
          <div>no button selected</div>
          <div>first button selected</div>
          <div>second button selected</div>
          <div>third button selected</div>
        </div>
      );
    }
  };

  render() {
    //const classes = useStyles();
    const { classes } = this.props;
    //  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);

    return (
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <AppBar position="static">
          <Tabs value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
            <Tab label="Item One" />
            <Tab label="Item Two" />
            <Tab label="Item Three" />
          </Tabs>
        </AppBar>
        {this.state.value === 0 && (
          <TabContainer>
            Item One
            <Button onClick={this.selectButton}>button one</Button>
          </TabContainer>
        )}
        {this.state.value === 1 && (
          <TabContainer>
            Item Two <Button onClick={this.selectButton}>button two</Button>
          </TabContainer>
        )}
        {this.state.value === 2 && (
          <TabContainer>
            Item Three <Button onClick={this.selectButton}>button three</Button>
          </TabContainer>
        )}

        {this.renderButtonSelection()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withStyles(styles)(SimpleTabs);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this is what you are looking for:

Replaced the selectButton and renderButtonSelection methods with the below:

```
getNumStr = n => {
    switch (n) {
    case 1:
        return "one";
    case 2:
        return "two";
    case 3:
        return "three";
    default:
        return "";
    }
};

selectButton = e => {
  const selectedButtonTarget = this.state.value + 1;
  this.setState({ selectedButton: selectedButtonTarget });
};

renderButtonSelection = () => {
  if (this.state.selectedButton) {
    return <div>button {this.getNumStr(this.state.selectedButton)} selected</div>;
  }
  return null;
};
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-c4mnj

Comment: hey instead of number one, can you get the output in wordings as number one...can you give comments too

Comment: Updated the answer. :)

Comment: hey it should be button 3 selected not as button three selected

Comment: button one selected, button two selected and button 3 selected?

Comment: all three as numbers not as alphabets

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195581/discussion-between-sreeram-and-zi-zi).

Comment: i saw all alphabets initially :(

Comment: @zizi this is also to help you put the stuff together yourself. stackoverflow is not a place to get the code written for you